# Personal desktop wiki with automatic linking

Tags: windows-7, note-taking, desktop-client, wiki, autocomplete

After a long time looking for a personal wiki / note-taking application I've come to the conclusion there's no wiki with exactly or at least most of the features I need. I need the wiki to keep track of solved programming problems at work but also for personal notes.

**Features**

These *must* be the following …

- Automatic linking of entries by typing the keyword / title of another entry, preferably with autosuggestion, **also non camel case titles with spaces** (Zim desktop wiki doesn't support this)
- Attaching all kind of files to an entry
- Searching the whole wiki for a word and showing all related entries
- Desktop-based (Windows 7)
- Ease of use of [Tomboy](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy), [WikiPad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) is no fun

and it *would be nice* to have these …

- LaTeX support
- A portable version
- Insert programming code with syntax highlighting and correct formatting
- Free

What I've tried and didn't like …

- Zim (link words can't be non camel case)
- Tomboy (no files or pictures can be attached or inserted into an entry)
- WikiPad (no spaces in keywords?)
- ConnectedText (too overloaded)

@jf1 Is it possible to automatically link to other notes **without** typing the name of the other note in square brackets first? Thats the most important feature i'd like to have: Linking, without having me to do anything - just typing the text.

I'm having OneNote 2010 here and it doesn't seem to work this way. Does the current version (2016) support this?

Answer (score 1):

I use [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/) for a personal information repository (type Wiki) of notes about software development, this tool covers most items you require.

**Features**

- Portable. (One single file, You can stored it in dropbox for get a copy in every moment in each linked device)
- It works in different plataforms (Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, Safari, Android, ipad/iphone, Node.js, WebDAV)
- Ease of use, configure and add new plugins. [Drag and Drop]
- Insert programming code with syntax [highlighting](http://tiddlywiki.com/plugins/tiddlywiki/highlight/) in several languages.
- Open Source (https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5)
- Soporte [KaTeX](http://tiddlywiki.com/plugins/tiddlywiki/katex/), (plugin for mathematical typesetting based on KaTeX from Khan Academy.)
- Attaching all kind of files to an entry
- Searching the whole wiki for a word and showing all related entries.
- Manual Links, CamelCase Links, External Links,  Customising Tiddler Links.
- For default Automatic linking is not enabled, but you can development this feature about your needs, for example you can get this performance with a [macro](http://tiddlywiki.narkive.com/50URFT7x/tw-automatic-linking-possible-in-tiddlywiki)

[image: Demo Download Tiddlywiki]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try OneNote, which fullfills
all your given requirements and some of the
additional requests:

https://www.onenote.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it seems OneNote can't link automatically to other notes by just typing. You have to type the name in square brackets first. I wan't it to link instantly after typing the title of an existing note, without me knowing this note exists or not.

Comment: @foxl Indeed you have to type square brackets. However, the referenced page need not exist. If it does, then it is linked, otherwise it gets created on the fly and linked, as soon as you close with the 2nd square bracket. But I see, you want it the other way around. I'm sorry, the closest with this regard is TomBoy, i think. But you already said you don't like it.... Moreover, with spaces in page names, hmh. you seem to be out of luck; how should the software know, where you intend the name to end, if you don't want to provide at least a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same kind of software for a long time and now am very happy with [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/).

[image: Screenshot of Obsidian "Start Here" page]

It supports all of your *must* features:

- **Linking** between files using the `[[Title of Page]]` syntax, with auto-completion for titles (or assigned aliases), with support for spaces and different cases (i.e. no camel case titles). Internal links also show a preview of the linked wiki page on mouse hover.
- **Attaching** any kind of files. You can even preview PDF documents, images/GIFs, audio- and video files, ... directly as embedded blocks on a page. There is also support for `iframe`, e.g. embedded YouTube videos, etc.
- Advanced **search** features; including searching all files for a word and showing all related files in real-time.
- **Desktop-based** (runs on Windows, Mac and Linux). Supports a desktop workflow through lots of configurable hotkeys, etc.
- **Easy to use**, due to Markdown+ syntax and helpful GUI elements.

It also supports most of your *nice to have* features:

- **LaTeX** support (inline and display).
- Display **code** with syntax highlighting
- **Free**.
- While the Obsidian application itself is not portable, all created wikis including their associated Obsidian settings are (and therefore can be used from USB-drives or cloud folders).

---

Additional features I want to point out:

- Drag-and-drop
- Sublime-like command palette
- Third-party plugin support.
- Custom themes (using css) and light-/dark modes.
- Presentation mode, which can display a wiki page as a presentation with slides.
- (Optional) integrated audio recorder to directly generate embedded audio notes.
- Force-directed graph view of your wiki, with filtering options and dynamic groups.